# SQL: Default values for Dropdowns in Database

Tags: sql, drop-down-menu, default

A coworker and I are in a debate in what would be best practices dealing with default values in the database and populating a drop down with it.

My Perspective: Put the default values in the database. `Blank` and `Not Completed` are valid options and should be kept in the database as an option to select.

His Perspective: Remove the default values from the database. For the first item, if it's not in the database, then the code should provide a default value. If any other value is selected, then that's stored off to the database, otherwise it's `NULL`.

This may start a debate, but I'm just looking for people's opinions more than anything.

Comment: The best practice is the one most appropriate for the situation at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, like most things, it depends.  If `Not Completed` is a valid value within the context of your data, then it should be in the database.  For example, if you need to indicate that a particular field on a form was Not Completed by the user.  However, if you are trying to indicate missing data, then `NULL` is the way to go.

Comment: Both answers were awesome answers, but from the looks of it, we're going to be going with the route above. Since "Not Completed" is a valid value within the context of our data, it made sense to put it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep the default values off the database. My defaults are mostly NULL, if not set.

**Reason:**

You can easily manage your defaults in the database model-classes. It's important to save IDs or keys - instead of words or sentences - in the database, if you want to provide multi-language.

If you'd save any key or any number, nobody knows where it comes from and may cause a misunderstanding in teams.

Pro:

- the code is easy to read/manage
- IDs or keys increase the performance (e.q. VARCHAR vs. TINYINT)

Con:

- Don't know any.

Example:

```
# Model
class User_Model {

    const STATUS_DEFAULT       = null;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE        = 1;
    const STATUS_INACTIVE      = 2;
    const STATUS_BANNED        = 3;
    const STATUS_NOT_COMPLETED = 4; // you could save the int 4         
                                    // instead of varchar "not completed"

    public function __construct() {
        self::STATUS_DEFAULT = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
    }
}

# simple multi-language
$lang            = "en";
$languages       = array();
$languages["en"] = array(
    "user_status_1" => "active",
    "user_status_2" => "not active",
    "user_status_3" => "banned",
    "user_status_4" => "not completed"
);

echo $languages[$lang]["user_status_4"]; // output: not completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for stating your opinions on this. 
Dan Bracuk put it best
"The best practice is the one most appropriate for the situation at hand."
For out needs, putting the default values into the database made more sense.